# How to draw a PolyLine in Folium if it wouldn't interesect another PolyLine

Tags: python, geospatial, folium

I am using Folium to plot my millions of Google Location History data points. My objective is to see which streets I've visited in the city that I live in. The problem I have is that the PolyLines overlap each other. I would like to only draw a PolyLine if it would not overlap another PolyLine. Is there a away to do this in Folium?

```
map = folium.Map(location=[coord1, coord2])
for i in range(len(df)):
    folium.PolyLine(([df.iloc[i]['lat'], df.iloc[i]['lon']],
    [df.iloc[i+1]['lat'], df.iloc[i+1]['lon']] ), 
    no_clip=True, smooth_factor=1).add_to(map)
        count += 1
    if count > 10000:
        break
map.save('test.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to see if the line segments AB and CD intersect:

```
def intersect(A, B, C, D):
    """
    Check if line segments AB and CD intersect
    """
    def ccw(A,B,C):
        return (C[1]-A[1]) * (B[0]-A[0]) > (B[1]-A[1]) * (C[0]-A[0])
    
    return ccw(A,C,D) != ccw(B,C,D) and ccw(A,B,C) != ccw(A,B,D)
```

When adding a line to the map, compare it to all other polylines to see if they intersect, and if it doesn't intersect with any of them then draw the line.